Passing a User Defined Type of array string from C# to Oracle procedure throws an exception
In my Oracle Database 12c2, I defined this UDT.
CREATE TYPE TAFARRAY AS VARYING ARRAY (1000000) OF VARCHAR2(2000);

Then, I created a procedure and used this UDT as an input parameter.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROC(arrFirstName TAFARRAY)
AS
countUpdateRecords NUMBER(22,0) := 0;   
BEGIN
   
 loggerAutonomousCommit('Test - arrFirstName ',arrFirstName(1));
   
END MYPROC;

To test the procedure, I use this sql statement and it works as my expected.
DECLARE
  arr TAFARRAY := TAFARRAY('one', 'two', 'three');
BEGIN
  MYPROC(arr);
END;

Then, I create this C# method to pass an array of string to the procedure.
public async Task<string> ExecuteMyProcAsync()
{
    string[] param = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    string msg = string.Empty;

    OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection)this.Context.Database.Connection;
    if (oracleConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        oracleConnection.Open();

    using (OracleCommand oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            oracleCommand.CommandText = "MYPROC";
            oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oracleCommand.BindByName = true;

            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(CreateArrayParameter("arrFirstName", param));

            await oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    if (oracleConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        oracleConnection.Close();
    }
    return msg;
}

private OracleParameter CreateArrayParameter(string paramName, string[] paramValues)
{
    OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = paramName,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
        Value = paramValues,
        Size = paramValues.Length,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        //UdtTypeName = "TAFARRAY"
    };

    return param;
}

But, it throws an exception when executing the procedure.
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROC'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored'

I tried using UdtTypeName = "TAFARRAY", but still got the same error.
I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client v4.122.21.1.
What am I missing in the C# code? Thanks!
